# Singleton serialization in Kotlin

Tags: serialization, singleton, kotlin

I'm wondering if it's possible in Kotlin to deserialize (restore property values) of a declared object, **without having to manually assign the properties or resorting to reflection**. The following snippet further explains:

```
object Foo: Serializable {
    var propOne: String = ""
    // ...

    fun persist() {
        serialize(this) 
        // no problem with serialization
    }

    fun restore(bytes: ByteArray) {

        val fooObj: Foo = deserialize(bytes) as Foo
        // It seems Kotlin allows us to use singleton as type!

        // obvioulsly either of the following is wrong:
        // this = fooObj
        // Foo = fooObj

        // ... is there a way to 'recover' the singleton (object) other than 
        //     manual assignment of properties (or reflection) ???    
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a normal class here? A singleton with variables is essentially global mutable state.

Comment: @marstran: Setters can be made `private` or `internal`.

Comment: It is still global mutable state. It can be accessed globally, and it can mutate.

Comment: Yes, and both can be very bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to reassign the global reference to a singleton with a new instance.  At most you can write out the properties during serialization, and then on deserialization directly read the properties and mutate the state in the original object.  It will require custom code for you to assign the properties into the object either by direct assignment or reflection.  It would be better if you make your own singleton mechanism that holds an instance that you can swap out to be another instance that you deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

have faced with the same issue, and want to share with you my solution:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature
import java.io.File
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

typealias ObjMap = HashMap<String, Any?>

fun <T : Any> T.getInstance() : Any? {
    val target = if(this is Class<*>) this else javaClass

    return target.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE")?.get(null)
}

class ObjectHelper {
    companion object {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper().apply {
            enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        }

        fun objectToMap(obj: Any): ObjMap {
            var res = ObjMap()

            val instance = obj.getInstance()
            val o = instance ?: obj

            o.javaClass.declaredFields.forEach {
                if(it.name != "INSTANCE") {
                    it.isAccessible = true
                    val value = if(Modifier.isStatic(it.modifiers)) it.get(null) else it.get(o)
                    res[it.name] = value
                }
            }

            o.javaClass.classes.forEach {
                res[it.simpleName] = objectToMap(it)
            }

            return res
        }

        fun saveObject(path: String, obj: Any)  {
            mapper.writeValue(File(path), objectToMap(obj))
        }

        fun loadObject(path: String, obj: Any) {
            val json = mapper.readValue<HashMap<*,*>>(File(path), HashMap::class.java) as ObjMap

            loadObject(obj, json)
        }

         fun loadObject(obj: Any, props: ObjMap) {
            val objectParam = mapper.writeValueAsString(props)

            mapper.readValue(objectParam, obj::class.java)

            obj.javaClass.classes.forEach {
                val instance = it.getInstance()
                val map = props[it.simpleName]

                if(map != null && instance != null) {
                    loadObject(instance, map as ObjMap)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
 object TestObj {
        var f1: String = "f1"
        var f2: String = "f2"

        object TestObj_2 {
            var f1: String = "f1_1"
            var f2: String = "f2_2"
        }
    }

        TestObj.f1 = "aaa"
        saveObject("out.json", TestObj)

        TestObj.f1 = "bbb"
        loadObject("out.json", TestObj)

        println(TestObj.f1)
```

Result will be "aaa".